# User Home Folder not visible from WinSCP/FileZilla

Tags: centos, home

We have setup a Centos 7 FTP server. 
When we connect to it via WinSCP or FileZilla we get dropped in the user's Home Folder.

Once we go a layer above that, so the `/home` folder we do not see the user's Home Folder anymore.
However, if we type in the user's home folder manually it does jump to there.

Is it possible to see the User's Home Folder in WinSCP/FileZilla while the current directory is `/home`?

```
ls -ld /home /home/ftp/ 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 17 Apr  2 16:11 /home
drwx------. 2 ftp  ftp  99 Apr  2 16:04 /home/ftp/
```

/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/user_list
userlist_deny=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

https://media.giphy.com/media/L0GekGXOCwUOxv2TWL/giphy.mp4

Comment: [ftp@csi_ftp_intern /]$ ls -ld /home /home/ftp
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 17 Apr  2 16:11 /home
drwx------. 2 ftp  ftp  99 Apr  2 16:04 /home/ftp

Comment: It has been done

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these directory permissions so I would guess it's a directive in your FTP Server configuation. Can you include the non-comment lines from that in your question too, please. Oh, and confirm to us which FTP Server tool you're using.

Comment: The vsftpd config has been added

Comment: Selinux enabled?  You’ll need to have the selinux Boolean “ftpd_full_access” if you want it to be able to read anywhere not labeled public_content_t.  And please don’t turn off selinux.

Comment: @jsbillings you're right, that solved it.
If you want you can post your anwser and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selinux enabled?

You’ll need to have the selinux Boolean “`ftpd_full_access`” if you want it to be able to read anywhere not labeled `public_content_t`.

(And please don’t turn off selinux.)

Comment: setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1 is the command